# are ICEFaces/RichFaces/PrimeFaces applications RIA?

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, ria, icefaces

With the word RIA you mean something based on client extra-html code (flash, flex, applet javafx, silverlight) or anything that gives a better usability?
 
If so, also AJAX would be included, and since it's the base for *Faces technologies, they would be RIA too.
Wikipedia seems to exclude ajax from RIA, in favor to the distinction ria vs. ajax.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, Ajax and RIA are different things, but using HTML, Javascript and Ajax you can build Rich Interfaces.

For Example, you can't say 'gmail' is not a RIA becouse it not uses Flex or JavaFX.

Comment: of corse they are different things. but if you say that gmail is RIA because 'it's rich', so you intend RIA is both the ajax (htmll) way AND the runtime way (flex, silverlight, javafx etc.). RIA in a broader sense.

Comment: well. so icefaces or the other *faces ARE ria components

Comment: well, listening to them, they are "ICEfaces 2 is an open-source Rich Internet Application (RIA) development framework based on the JavaServer Faces (JSF) 2 standard."